# How to include GET variables in URL with Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

If you check out my site [here](http://techxpertschico.com/) you can see that I used ajax to do all the page loads, the issue is that none of the get variables end up in the URL. This is bad for a variety of reasons, the biggest being that I obviously can't provide links to specific pages. I'm not quite sure what to change. Push me in the right direction and I will go and teach myself if thats what it takes, I just need the push. Thanks!

All of the links are ajaxAnchors

```
$('.ajaxAnchor').on('click', function (event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('section.center').html(data);
    });
});
```

Let me know if you need any other code and I'll do my best to add it

Added this... truncated it a bit to show just up to the first anchor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chico TechXperts</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section id="wrap">
        <header class="header" >
            <hgroup>
                <embed id="logo" src="images/techxpertslogo.svg" width="100px" height="100px" type="image/svg+xml" />
                <h1 class="header">TechXperts Chico</h1>
                <h2 class="header">Technology Training and Repair 592-0886</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </header>
<nav class="top">
        <a class="ajaxAnchor" href="home.html">
                    <div id="navOne" class="top">
                        <span class="top">Home</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
</nav>
            </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$(this).attr('href');`? Or please show relevant HTML too

Comment: cant you just header locations ? $(location).attr('href', 'http://www.yousite.com?a=1&b=2');

Comment: What `GET` variables? None of the URLs on the page have any parameters.

Comment: Just learn to use Meteor.js and iron-router. It automagically does all this work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an all-ajax site, you'll need to use the History api to update the URLs.

I recommend [HistoryJS](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) to manage this, cross-browser.

Basically when you change the page content, you'll call pushState (or replaceState), to store the 'state' of your site/app.  This state can be any JS object you like.
You push or replace the state, giving a URL.  This can alter the browser URL (and in history) without forcing a page reload.

Then you'll handle the onPopState event to process the 'state' when the user navigates (e.g. back button).

From your description, the main direct advantage you'll get is being able to update the URL (enabling linking etc.) without forcing the whole page to reload.

**Edit:** [Here's](http://codepen.io/lingo/pen/KmGdr) a small demo of using History.js
Note: you'll need to see this in CodePen's debug view in order to actually see it working right.  CodePen seems to provide a frame which prevents you seeing the URL/Title changes.
I recommend Forking this example to play around with it in Debug view.

Comment: Was it a bad idea to go all ajax? I was trying to teach myself ajax as well as make a "modern" browsing experience but it seems like I might have broken some unwritten web design rules. What do you think?

Comment: Also do you mind showing a code snippet of what using HistoryJS with my ajaxAnchor jquery might look like?

Comment: Well, I certainly would provide a NOSCRIPT fallback of some kind, to inform people without javascript running.  When running with javascript disabled a lot of sites these days present as a completely blank page!

Comment: Great observation, and let me just say DAYYYYUM this demo using history.js looks excellent. Ajax with history.js is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the URL hash:

```
<a href="#repair" class="ajaxAnchor">Repair</a>
```

When a link is clicked and the hash changes, check the hash to determine which page to load:

```
$('.ajaxAnchor').on('click', function (event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    if (hash && hash.length > 0) {
      var url = hash + '.html';    
      $.get(url, function(data) {
          $('section.center').html(data);
      });    
    }
});
```

You can listen for the `hashchange` event, but I recommend using the [jQuery Address plugin](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address/) and using the `$.address.externalChange` function, as it works with older versions of IE that don't support the `hashchange` event.

To direct link to a page, just check for a hash after the page loads and then load the correct data accordingly.

This approach also has the advantage of enabling navigation with the back and forward buttons.

Comment: I believe that History.js will automatically use hashes when HTML4 is detected.